# to_field not working in ForeignKey relationship in django

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-key-relationship

i am trying to link my **comments** model to the **username** field of the **auth user** model.
here is the **code**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from urllib.parse import urlparse


class Posts(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    url = models.URLField()
    points = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    moderator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="moderated_stories")
    voters = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="liked_stories", blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    @property
    def domain(self):
            return urlparse(self.url).netloc

    def __str__(self):
            return self.title + " by " + self.moderator.username

    class Meta:
            verbose_name_plural = "stories"


class Comments(models.Model):

    comment = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="commented_on", to_field="username")
    commented_on = models.ForeignKey(Posts, related_name="comments")

    def __str__(self):
            return self.comment + " by " + self.user

    class Meta:
            verbose_name_plural = "comments"
```

but on executing queries it gives me following error:

```
>>> post = Posts.objects.get(id=2)
>>> post.comments.all()
django.contrib.auth.models.DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist.
```

but when i execute query to serialize the data it works

```
>>> serializers.serialize('json', post.comments.all())
'[{"model": "news.comments", "pk": 1, "fields": {"comment": "Thanks for sharing
the link :)", "commented_on": 2, "created_at": "2015-09-30T06:01:40.201Z", "user
": 1}}, {"model": "news.comments", "pk": 2, "fields": {"comment": "this is what
i was looking for...!", "commented_on": 2, "created_at": "2015-09-30T06:02:17.4
97Z", "user": 4}}, {"model": "news.comments", "pk": 3, "fields": {"comment": "th
anks for sharing !", "commented_on": 2, "created_at": "2015-09-30T06:02:43.971Z"
, "user": 3}}]'
```

but the serialized data still contains the **PK** of the user and not the **username**.
what is wrong with this code?

Comment: If you changed the `to_field` after creating the Comment model, then you'll have to update the values to store the usernames instead of the user ids. If you are doing this to change the output of your serializer, then it's probably not the best approach -- it should be possible to keep the foreign key as it is, but show the username when serializing comments.

Comment: yes it worked ! i will try to get the username by keeping the foreign key as it is. Thanks a lot for your help :)